# what does 'I'm not for pretending' mean?

Tags: meaning

What does this sentence mean?

> I'm not for pretending.

Also, is this a correct sentence?

> I don't get used to it.

Comment: Hello, Rose.  You might be seeking help from the wrong site.  You might be a learner of English.  If you are, try the English Language Learners site.  Also, please try to make your question clearer.  Give the context:  what comes just before and just after "I'm not for pretending".  I guess that 'for' is used to mean 'in favour of'.  So the writer would be saying she or he does not want to pretend or is against pretending.  In English, 'for', can be used as the opposite of 'against'.  But without knowing what comes before it and after it, I cannot be sure.

Comment: @Tuffy: In many contexts (including perhaps OP's, which hasn't been *precisely* specified), ***He's not for X*** and ***X isn't for him*** are equivalent and interchangeable. Where the "meaning" of ***for*** is closer to ***compatible with, capable of co-existing with*** than ***in favour of***.

Comment: Yes indeed:  and ‘The lady is not for burning’.  I was just taking what struck me as the most probable guess to illustrate why more context is needed.  Thanks for reinforcing the need.

Answer (score 1):

*To be for X* means

- you would vote for X if a vote was taken, or otherwise would approve of it,
- you can't control X, X is made, created, or performed by someone or something else.

So "I'm not for pretending" likely means you are in a group of people, some of them want to pretend, others don't, and you are "casting your vote" with the others.

---

> I don't get used to it.

This is grammatically correct.  This means something happens to you regularly and you never get used to it, each time it happens.

If something is happening now and you don't get used to it, you should say *I'm not getting used to it* instead.